# Odoo Qweb Report and database vues

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I started to learn Odoo Qweb report by reading the documentation here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html

for the invoice report, i saw in my database vue that there is a vue called account_invoice_report and i guess this vue is called to get information about the report content.

my Question are:

- Where this vue is call in python file?
- I want to create my own database vue  and call it in pyhton  to create a report( simple view with to tables) can someone share with me a link explaining how to perform that?

I learned that when you define a model with a _name="myname", Odoo will create a corresponding table if it doesn't exist, is it the same way with view?

Thank you

Comment: You're mixing up database view for Odoo's dashboards/graph views and QWeb reports for Odoo's documents (for printing) here. Of course you can use database views for documents, but do you really want that? Just asking...

Comment: When I was making custom report this documentation gave me complete instructions so, read it again, and use source code. It's not a question that I can answer with few lines of text + I'm too lazy to give you complete example, but I cat tell you that documentation is enough

Comment: Look at `account/account_invoice.py` for `invoice_print` method.If you want to create your own report look at http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/creating-custom-reports-odoo-8/

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I don't want a complete example. I just want to know how to get values of my database view in Odoo Class. Then i will adapt the report regarding the link i provided.